# How to configure Sublime Text 2/3 to use direct Ctrl+Tab order and to create new tabs after the last one?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

When I press Ctrl+Tab, Ctrl+Shift+Tab or Ctrl+W the tab I get switched to is not the one just near the one I was on (as I would like to) but to some else. When I press Ctl+N the new tab is created right near the tab I am at while I always want it to be created at the end of the tabs list. How to configure it to achieve the behaviour I desire?

Answer (score 233):

To achieve the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behavior you can add the following lines to your `sublime-keymap`:

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+tab"], "command": "next_view" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+tab"], "command": "prev_view" }
```

To open `sublime-keymap`:

1. click "Preferences"
2. click "Key Bindings"
3. You will see two settings file, select a file that named "User"

---

This is a visual example on how it should look.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What about changing where does a new tab appear and where do I get when I close a tab?

Comment: Unfortunately these other configs I haven't been able to achieve yet :\

Comment: @Miguelgraz See my answer for a solution to new file.

Comment: For people who don't know how to directly edit the `sublime-keymap` (like me): Click preferences -> Key Bindings - User. Copy above code in the file (between the brackets)

Comment: 1 little side note, if your user key bindings file is completely empty, put the above code between these: `[` key bindings here `]`. After one frustrating our finally found that out, so I hope that this will help somebody in the future.

Comment: Totally true @Mathlight, I'm really sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Using Sublime Text 2 here, and awesome, working just fine - thanks for this!  Now if only I could figure out how to keep this behaviour when *closing* a tab...

Comment: @Breakthrough What do you mean?

Comment: is there still no way to open new tabs at the end of the tab list (without using a plugin)? thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

With the default key bindings, <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Page Down</kbd> will allow you to move right and left among your open tabs, respectively, in their visual order. (The keybinding solution replicates this functionality using your preferred keys.)

Because the package installer is now included with Sublime Text, it's also straightforward to add the MoveTab extension, which adds the shortcuts <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Page Down</kbd> to move the current tab within that visual order.

To access the package installer in Sublime  Text 3 (in Windows, anyway), type <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>, then `Package Control: Install Package`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin to get the new file behavior you want.

```
import sublime_plugin

class MyNewFile(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        window = self.window
        view = window.new_file()
        active_group = window.active_group()
        views_in_group = window.views_in_group(active_group)
        window.set_view_index(view, active_group, len(views_in_group) - 1)
```

Save the above in `Packages/User` as `<somename>.py`. Then use the command `my_new_file` in your key binding for `ctrl+n` I wouldn't be surprised if there was aplugin to do this already, but it's pretty simple, so easier to write it yourself, than to search package control :) You can likely lose a plugin to do what you want for `ctrl+w` also, but you didn't describe the behavior you wanted.

Comment: I have described the behaviour I want for Ctrl+W - close the active tab and move to the tab right near (now it closes the active tab and moves to some other tab, using the same logic as Ctrl+Tab does by default most probably).

Comment: I think https://github.com/facelessuser/TabsExtra will do what you want. The default logic looks to fallback to the right. I haven't used the plugin, but by description it looks correct.